# Small atrium in 3rd floor of building has a storm drain that's leaking down to the crawlspace. How do i fix this?

Tags: leak, drain, waterproofing, drainage, water-damage

My building (*old 4 unit Victorian*) has a small atrium on the 3rd floor with a storm drain that's leaking all the way down to the crawlspace underneath the building.

When it rains, i can hear light drips of water inside my walls underneath the atrium (*2 floors down*).

We had a plumber come by to snake the storm drain, and it does sound like less water is dripping  now, but it's still not 100%

Any suggestions on how to address this without completely tearing out the walls in 3 floors??

Comment: is the drain leaking or the floor of the atrium?

Comment: does the storm drain connect with other drains between the atrium and the crawlspace?

Comment: Do you have a photo of the floor? It may be like Jasen suggests the floor is leaking at or close to the drain.

Comment: Oh interesting, that's a good call.

I can't really get into the atrium, so i'm not totally sure which it could be.
The Atrium is above a closet though, and the closet is above another space. As far as i know, neither of those spaces have any water damage. totally possible it's all just dripping through the walls... 

Is there any easy way to test whether it's the pipe vs. floors? (I assume filling it up with water?)

No other drains connecting afaik.